# Using AND and OR in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I'm trying to use the OR operator in assembly.

This is the first logic condition:

```
cmp byte ptr [bx], '+'
jz perm_oper
cmp byte ptr [bx], '-'
jz perm_oper
```

I'm trying to shorten it using the OR operator. But for some reason isn't giving the same results:

```
cmp byte ptr [bx], '+'
OR byte ptr [bx], '-'
jz perm_oper
```

What am I doing wrong? What is the equivalent using OR of the first snippet?

Comment: `or` is OR-ing its operands, not status flags.

Comment: More precisely, `or` is [bitwise OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR).

Comment: In the big picture, what you're doing wrong is thinking that somehow two comparisons can be mechanically reduced to a single comparison and an OR. Do the two comparisons and OR the results, yes that's doable, but you can't just eliminate a comparison like that and retain the original meaning.

Comment: I read the articule but I really don't understand how it works. Can this be used to shorten long comparisons in assembly? I used a short example in the question, but I have a long string of comparisons in my code and using something sort of || would make my life easier

Comment: If you want them to short-circuit like the C `||` operator, you need separate jumps for each one. That's what the version with the two `jz`s does, and it's really about as short as it can be. If you want them to *not* short-circuit, you need to copy the Z flag to another register, OR each new result with the running result, and do a single `jz` at the end.

Comment: @Wumpus Q. Wumbley how is that doable? could you answer doing it in the example? I need a clear example of how the syntaxis would be. I have really long chains of cmp I need to shorten

Comment: thanks, it'll remain that way then

Answer (score 0):

If you can do things in an orderly manner

```
 mov cx,(whatever)
 repz scasb
```

may work for you